# Script not loading when redirecting to a view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, youtube-api

I am new to AngularJS and I have an app where I am playing a youtube video in popup using AngularJS.

The problem in that is, whenever the page is loaded using F5 or 'reload' from brower, the associated script to load the youtube player works fine but whenever I navigate to that page anywhere from my app, then that script does not work.

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
  videoId: 'iSCIesIM8Ww'
});
}
 </script>
```

This is the script I want to load Each time the page is viewed.

Moreover I have written this script in one of my partial views file.

I have also did it using an directive but that didn't solved the problem as well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't shout in your titles; you might think it attracts attention, and it does - but only bad attention.

Comment: Case in point: I came here only to ask you to not to shout in titles.

Answer (score 1):

Please create a directive on the element of the partial view and include your javascript of video in your directive.It will work perfect into that.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mahendra Tyagi. Yaa I tried that as well. Can you please provide me with an example so that I got to know that I am not doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to trigger the script after it's initial run.
This is because AngularJS apps are 'single page' apps and navigating inside the app doesn't trigger a full page refresh (by design). This is why Angular routes appear after the hash symbol 
 
`http://localhost:9000/#/myRoute`

Where did you place your directive? The directive JS will fire each time the directive is rendered. If the directive code isn't being run again it's because it isn't being re-rendered.

Comment: I placed my directive in a seperate JS file known as app.js. What can I do else ?

Comment: app.js is where you defined your directive. Where is it placed in your HTML? For instance: `<my-directive-name></my-directive-name>` This is what will determine how/how many times your directive is rendered.

Comment: Ohh, In that case, I placed my directive in one of the partial view file, 'main.html'